# using protractor to get the disabled attribute on button not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, selenium, protractor

I'm trying to get the disabled attr on a button it should be "disabled" but I don't seem to be getting the value. New to angular and protractor!

When I inspect the page this is what HTML I get for the button showing disabled is disabled, like it is on the page:

```
 <button type="submit" class="button primary inverse" ng-disabled="!comment.$dirty && comment.$valid" disabled="disabled">Save</button>
```

The protractor test below returns 'Expected null to equal disabled'

```
    var btnSave = element(by.css('.primary'));
    expect(btnSave.isPresent()).toBeTruthy();

    var attr = element(by.css('.primary')).getAttribute('disabled');

    expect(attr).toEqual("disabled");
```

When I try I get expected '' to equal disabled.

```
expect(attr).toEqual("disabled");
```

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Thanks

Comment: I wonder if  [`isEnabled()`](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.isEnabled) (or the Promisified `not` version of that) work to determine disabled?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`getAttribute()`](https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.getAttribute) function in protractor returns value in the form of promise. So either you have wait until its returned and then perform validation or you can pass in the function to the `expectation` which in turn resolves the promise. `disabled` html attribute is a [boolean attribute](https://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/infrastructure.html#boolean-attributes) and hence the value that it returns is either `true` or `false`. Here's how -

```
element(by.css('.primary')).getAttribute('disabled').then(function(attr){
    expect(attr).toBe(true);
});
```

OR

```
expect(element(by.css('.primary')).getAttribute('disabled')).toBe(true);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks. But I can only get it toequal " true" .So somewhere disabled="true" is being picked up.        element(by.css('.primary')).getAttribute('disabled').then(function (attr) {
            expect(attr).toBe("true");
        });

Comment: @thegunner disabled attribute doesn't have any value assigned to it as its a boolean attribute. You can check the presence of attribute name in this case by checking if the value is true. Updated answer with the same. Thanks

Comment: @thegunner disabled attribute doesn't have any value assigned to it as its a boolean attribute. You can check the presence of attribute name in this case by checking if the value is true. Updated answer with the same. Thanks