# How to validate if an element <button class="btn-blue" disabled> is disabled with protractor

Tags: javascript, html, protractor

I'm trying to validate if an element is enabled or not with protractor. here is the element:

```
<button class="btn-blue mat-raised-button" mat-raised-button="" type="button" disabled>
```

I tried to do it with `element.isEnabled()` but didn't work.

Comment: Does the button have a name?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [using protractor to get the disabled attribute on button not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35085024/using-protractor-to-get-the-disabled-attribute-on-button-not-working)

Comment: @PhotographyBum , no, the button doesn't have a name attribute

Answer (score 0):

The protractor API: `isEnabled()` should work on your scenario. But it will always return `false`. Because the button set the `disabled` attribute, according to the [HTML W3C Specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#enabling-and-disabling-form-controls:-the-disabled-attribute):
[image]

If use Assertion API of Jasmine: 
`expect(btn.isEnabled()).toEqual(false)`

If use Assertion API of [chai](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chai) and [chai-as-promised](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chai-as-promised) together: `expect(btn.isEnabled()).to.eventually.to.false;`